# Development ASP.NET Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, vss, visual-studio

We have an extra Windows 2003 Server that I am hoping can be used to speed up development process on a web site we're producing. We are trying to reduce lag time from our really slow ASP.Net local Development server by implementing a development server that hosts a dev version of our website though IIS.  I have multiple questions surrounding the possibility of doing this.

Environment:
Spare server (WinServ2k3) named "Spare"
Visual Source Safe (3 Users) holds our solutions on server "VSS"
Visual Studio runs on client A,B, and C
Visual Studio publishes releases to an externally hosted hosting service.

I'm not sure where to get started.  I know I could setup IIS to mirror what our production IIS server looks like.  But how would I change our debug to point to the development server?  And how do I propagate change to the development server through use of VSS (if some one else checked a file in, that change should be reflected in the development server).

Our asp.net development localhost servers just runs insanely slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few questions mixed in.

For a build environment continuous integration, check out [Go](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/go-agile-release-management), [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/) or [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/).

For performance, it could be because of a database connection over the Internet, or it could be other dependencies like web service calls.  You can narrow this down by starting with a test.htm and test.aspx page with just 'Hello World' for the content.  Walk the application until you narrow down the root cause of the performance.

Comment: Are you saying that in most cases an ASP.Net Development Server should be just as fast/responsive as the production IIS server?  This is not the case. The dev server does need to hit the internet to get ORM data whereas the IIS server does not, which I have to assume is the cause for the slowdown at this point.  I guess the only alternative would be to publish to two difference sources within the hosting provider if the sql query trips are the holdup. .

Comment: This all depends on your environment.  For development it's usually best to use a different connection string and a local database.  That should keep performance fast for your development environments, and ensure that no mistakes are made in the development data.  Then just transform the connection strings in your deployment (something that the continuous integration solutions address).  However, as a side, if you pull back the least about of data as possible with filtered queries, even requests over the internet can be fast. You may have some performance options in your queries.